# Exercise 1.5 from Big Rudin

Tags: measure-theory

> $X$ is a measurable space; if $f:X\longrightarrow [-\infty, +\infty]$
>   and $g:X\longrightarrow [-\infty, +\infty]$ are two measurable
>   functions, prove that the set $$\{x\in X\,: f(x)=g(x)\}$$ is
>   measurable.

the proof is simple if the range of $f$ and $g$ is $\mathbb R$, infact
$$\{x\in X\,: f(x)=g(x)\}=\{x\in X\,:f(x)-g(x)=0\}$$
but the last set is measurable because the difference of two measurable function is measurable and $\{0\}$ is a borelian. The problem is that in $[-\infty, +\infty]$ the function $f-g$ is not well defined!

Comment: I think there is an inevitable problem at points such as $\infty -\infty$, and to solve this problem, one may declare some values these points would take (i.e. $\infty -\infty=0$, same for other problematic values). Then proving f-g is measurable will be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x) < g(x)$ if and only if there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) < q < g(x)$. Thus we have
$$
\{f < g \} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} (\{f < q\} \cap \{q < g\}) 
$$
so $\{f < g\}$ is measurable since it is the countable union of measurable sets.
Of course $\{ f \neq g\} = \{f < g\} \cup \{g < f\}$ and $\{ f = g\} = \{ f \neq g\}^c$ so the measurability follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\{f=g\}= \bigg(\{f-g=0\}\cap \{f<\infty\} \cap \{g<\infty\}\bigg) \cup \bigg(\{f=\infty\} \cap \{g=\infty\}\bigg) \cup  \bigg(\{f=-\infty\} \cap \{g=-\infty\}\bigg) $$

where $\{g \in B\} := \{x \in X; g(x) \in B\}$ denotes the pre-image, for example $$\{g<\infty\} := \{x \in X; g(x)<\infty\}$$